# error when post file using urllib3 in python

Tags: python, post, python-requests, urllib3

I'm getting this error:
`b'{"status":"error","message":"Upload failed."}'`

I don't know why the file not getting uploaded. here is my code:

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = "https://tmpfiles.org/api/v1/upload"

dfile = open("image", "rb")
dfile=dfile.read()


response = http.request(
    "POST",
    url,
    fields={ "file": dfile }
)

print(response.data)
```

I tried using `requests`, and it works fine, but I want to use `urllib3` because it is faster

Comment: Is the website legit? Some antiviruses say it's suspicious.

Comment: yes it is legit, check it out https://tmpfiles.org/api

Comment: the server is down now

Comment: what makes you say that ?  In general, the urllib3 library is not significantly faster than the requests library for making HTTP requests. Both libraries use similar underlying HTTP libraries (such as httplib or http.client) to send and receive HTTP requests and responses, so the performance of the two libraries is likely to be similar.

Comment: What's the best way to do post request faster? I'm posting 30 files one time